# trying use of mouseover and mouseout in jquery

Tags: jquery

i show **ul**,(it shows my submenu) like floowing code , i have problem with hiding **ul**, while i move mouse over ul(into menu) , it hides, and i cound not use of   mouseout event correctly

how could i hide ul, just when mouseout of "ul li"

```
$("ul li").mouseover(function() {
   $(this).find('ul').show();

  }).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).find('ul').hide();
  });
```

Comment: Well how can you hide the ul if your mouseout event is on the ul? It will be hidden thus not showing the mouse out surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method which binds to the [`mousenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events, like this:

```
$("ul li").hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').show();
}, function(){
  $(this).find('ul').hide();
});
```

Or, if the children are initially hidden, you can shorten it further with [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), like this:

```
$("ul li").hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

The main difference is that [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) *doesn't* fire when **entering a child** where as [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) *does*.  Also [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) doesn't fire for descendant elements either, which is what you want in the case of your menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bind method instead:

```
$("ul li").bind("mouseenter",function() {

});

$("ul li").bind("mouseleave",function() {

});
```